# Multinomial logit using rstanarm

Tags: r, multinomial, stan, rstan

I know that you can fit a binomial logit model with the `rstanarm` package by using `stan_glm` and setting `family = binomial(link="logit")`, but does `rstanarm` give you the option to fit a multinomial logit model ?

I found this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24705/can-i-use-glm-algorithms-to-do-a-multinomial-logistic-regression

but i am confused on how to translate the model `Y=A+BX` into the form that is mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multinomial logit model cannot currently be estimated with the **rstanarm** R package. There is a long-standing [issue](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/issues/20) to implement it, which would not be too difficult, but we have been more focused on the more difficult problem of getting a multinomial probit model implemented. I believe you can do a multinomial logit model with the `brm` function in the **brms** R package, which also uses Stan to draw from the posterior distribution.

Comment: UPDATE: is there multinomial/categorical logit regression in `rstanarm` or `brms` available now? I am talking about a stan program that does something like this `fit <- multinom(y~ x1+ x2+ x3, data = df)` as explained here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-12/topics/multinom. Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

The `brms` supports multinomial models. Here are two methods:

```
library(foreign) 
library(brms)

#data source: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/
ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")

#Method 1:
m1 <- brm(prog2 ~ ses + write, data = ml, family = multinomial(link = "logit"))
summary(m1)

#Method 2:
m2 <- brm(prog ~ ses + write, data = ml, family = categorical(link = "logit"))
summary(m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stan_polr`, see "[Regression and Other Stories](https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/)" for an example (section 15.5). E.g.

```
library(rstanarm)
fit <- stan_polr(factor(vote) ~ value, data = data_401, prior = R2(0.3, "mean))
```

Taken from https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/Storable/storable.html